# Meteor allow update: I'm trying to let any user "join" a post, but only the post creator can edit a post?

Tags: permissions, meteor

So I'm trying to build an app kinda similar to the Parties example on the main Meteor page.  In the Parties app you can create a party and invite people to it or make it public.  What i'd like to do is change it so that even if it's a public party you still have to join it through clicking a button.

I have that working except that through console.logs i've figured out that it's not allowed because the user that clicks the Join button is trying to update the Event but currently only the event start has access to updating.

So this is correct

```
var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    var currentEventId = this._id;

    Events.update(currentEventId, {$addToSet: { attendees: currentUser }}, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        if (error) {
            throwError(error.reason);
        } else {
            Router.go('eventPage', {_id: currentEventId});
        }
```

but now I need to change this it seems

```
Events.allow({
update: ownsDocument,
remove: ownsDocument});

ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {
    return doc && doc.userId === userId;
}
```

So I think i need to change the update to say something like:

If you're not a user you need to join or login.  If you are a user but not the event creator then you can add your userId to the attendees array.  If you are the event creator then you can edit the event.  I just don't really know if that's allowed in an allow update function or how to write it really since I'm still a fairly newbie at JS.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, make sure you remove the `insecure` package, from `.meteor/packages`.

I would suggest to only implement *basic* `allow`/`deny` rules. Eg, owner can update certain fields.

For anything slightly more complicated, use `Meteor.methods`. Methods will ignore the allow & deny rules, and let you perform more complicated actions.

Methods are always executed/confirmed server side, and can optionally have 'simulations' on the client so that it appears as though it was executed immediately!

For example, a method to add the currently logged in user to an event-

```
Meteor.methods({
  'attendEvent': function(eventId){
    // check they're logged in
    check(this.userId, String);
    // check the eventId isn't something un-expected
    check(eventId, String);
    // add the user to `attendees`, using `$addToSet` as each user can only attend once
    Events.update({_id: eventId}, {$addToSet: { attendees: this.userId}});
  }
});
```

You can then call the action on the client like:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
   'click a[data-action="attendEvent"][data-event]': function(e){
      // get the eventId from element data- however data could be available in this.eventId / this._id too!
      var eventId = $(e.currentTarget).data('event')
      Meteor.call('attendEvent', eventId)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Pretty sure this makes sense.  So leave what I currently have for the allow and deny, and just add this method.  If this method happens then it doesn't even bother checking the allow/deny otherwise only the event owner can modify stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `allow()` function to match the logic you want.  Change your `update:` to:

```
update: function( userId, doc, fields, modifier ){
   return ( doc &&  doc.userId === userId ) || ( userId && modifier === {$addToSet: { attendees: userId}} );
},
```

You would probably also want to add an `if` to check `currentUser` on the client before calling `Events.update() since it will fail.

Comment: This answers it too and very succinctly, but I ended up learning something extra from the other answer.  I wish I could give you both the imaginary karma but I don't even have the rep to give any.